# I have an image problem and I don't know what to call this

Tags: image-quality, image-processing, noise

I wrote the article using a translator and hope you understand well, Sorry...

I am developing machine vision using basler camera(acA2440-20gm).

A problem arose during development.

The image contains things like noise.

I want to know what this is and how to get rid of it.

[image]

This is image with gamma correction.
[image]

If you zoom in, you will see a line like the picture below.

[image]

What is this?

And this is raw image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you describing the stair-step appearance of the high-contrast curve?  Context from the full image would be helpful to figure out the cause.

Comment: @xiota 
I edited the article.
plz help me...ㅠ

Comment: The vertical line is not present in your "original" image. Thus, the program used to change the gamma is probably at fault. The noise (not the vertical line) is compression artifacts which is strange since PNG doesn't use lossy compression. Looks like you used JPEG at some point in your conversion.

Comment: @qrk 
I uploaded image with zoom in. 
Also visible in raw images.

Comment: That's NOT really "THE raw image" because there is no such thing. That's just a different interpretation of the data in the raw image file that has been processed differently than the other example. You're never actually looking at unprocessed raw data on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your vertical line looks like a missed scan line (see the notches at both ends). If you cut the image on the line and drag the right part one more pixel to the right the result looks rounder. Hardware problem? Bug in imaging software? Hard to tell from here.

[image]

Simulation of the problem by removing a vertical line on a CGI:

[image]